# How to format line on scatter plot

Tags: pandas, linear-regression, scatter-plot, coefficients

I need the line to reach the end corners of the graph, and also need to change the color of the line to red. My code:

```
plt.figure(),
plt.subplot(211) 
plt.scatter(df.NOX, df.PTRATIO)
b, m = polyfit(x, y, 1)
plt.plot(x, y, '.' )
plt.plot(x, b + m * x, '-' )
plt.show()
```

[Scatterplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T9vtn.png)

I also need to do the same for this scatterplot.
[Scatterplot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8uuGS.png)
The code I used:

```
X_prime = np.linspace(df.PTRATIO.min(), df.PTRATIO.max(), 100)
X_prime = sm.add_constant(X_prime)
y_hat = lr_model1.predict(X_prime)

plt.figure()
plt.subplot(211) 
plt.scatter(df.NOX, df.PTRATIO)

plt.subplot(212)
plt.scatter(X.NOX, y)
plt.plot(X_prime[:,1], y_hat, 'red', alpha=0.9)
```

The output is inaccurate for Scatterplot 2: 
[Scatterplot 2 output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qSzqY.png)

Sample data screenshot: [Sample Data screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gGQA7.png)

Comment: can you share sample data?

Comment: Unfortunately, the Excel file is greyed out when I try to attach it. I an screenshot it, though.